# What does 気が遠い mean?

Tags: translation

Could someone help me translate this?

> ２２歳でこんなことも思い出せない。。。あせる
>   これから**気が遠い**よ

I think the first sentence is something about being 22 years old and not remembering well. As for the second sentence, I can only make out "from now on, feel far" (??).

I am not sure how the second sentence relates to the first one.

Comment: Can you at least try to explain what you do know already and where the source of your confusion is? Perhaps attempt a translation yourself.

Comment: I think it's something about being 22 years old and not remembering well. As for the second sentence, I can only make out "from now on, feel far" ??

Comment: 「２２才で、まだ若いのに、こんなことも思い出せない。(ので、)焦る(≒心配になる/不安になる)。これから先(≒将来)のことを考えると、気が遠くなるよ。」って感じかなと思います・・・

Comment: Based on your comment, I edited the question to focus on 気が遠い.  Hopefully that's okay :-)

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question now... I voted to reopen!

Answer (score 6):

In this case 気が遠いよ expresses the feeling of helplessness that the narrator feels. As the above answer states, 気が遠い means to feel faint, but it's not necessarily meant literally here.

I would translate that whole passage as follows:

"I'm 22, still young, and yet I can't bring this back to mind. This frustrates me. And thinking about what the future might hold makes me feel faint."

The narrator is only young, but already feels as if she is suffering from the kind of memory loss associated with elderly people. And this state of affairs instills a sense of helplessness about how things are going to be for her from here on in.

Answer (score 5):

気が遠い typically means something like you feel far away, disconnected, swoon due to mental stress of some kind like it is difficult for you to comprehend what you are seeing or experiencing or your head is spinning because of sensory overload.  So my guess at what these two sentences mean, absent of more context is the following:

22 is still young, yet I can't recall even this... It frustrates me.  Thinking about what the future has in store for me makes my head spin.

Basically the person is trying very hard to recall something like this but just can't, so he/she is frustrated and flustered and it is causing their brain to hurt trying to recall it.

That's my interpretation at least. 英辞郎 has a lot of different examples of how 気が遠い (in the く form) can be translated.

Comment: Your TL sounds vague.  You could have made use of the good comment by Choko above.

Comment: Oh, missed that. Sorry a bit of noob here. I edited it with that in mind. Hopefully a little more accurate.